# Asp.net core web api Localization DataAnnotation custom attribute

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-localization

I'm trying to use localization with resource files, but it's not working, just for custom required attribute

```
public class RequiredIntAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        bool isValid = base.IsValid(value);

        if (isValid)
        {
            isValid =  int.Parse(value.ToString()) != 0;
        }

        return isValid;
    }
}

public class SalonForInsertDto
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NameEn { get; set; }

    [RequiredInt(ErrorMessage = "the userId is required")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Configure method add:

```
//localization & globalization
var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
```

Then in your custom validator class you add:

```
var _localizationService = (IStringLocalizer<SalonForInsertDto>)validationContext.GetService(typeof(IStringLocalizer<SalonForInsertDto>));
```

and then you are now able to get the localized string value from the resource file like:

```
_localizationService["How are you?"]
```

You can read about IStringLocalizer object and it's working in [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: what is validationContext and customData

Comment: I've got this error on validationContext an object reference is required for the non-static field

Comment: @KaviArshan you need to see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#alternatives-to-built-in-attributes